# About indirect object in sentence

Tags: objects, indirect-objects

I came across the sentence "He charges me money". Can the verb "charge" take an indirect object?

Comment: Yes, "money" is direct object and "me" is indirect object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> He charges me (indirect) money (direct).